# AJAX service call throwing error 12152

Tags: ajax

I am facing an issue with AJAX service call in IE8 whereas its working completely fine in IE9 and IE10. The error code linked with it is ERR:12152.
Is there a way round it? Please reply back with your solutions.

Thank You...

Comment: It seems to have something to do with McAfee. Do you have it installed?

Comment: you posted two different error numbers, which is it?

Comment: Sorry , Its my mistake.. It is 12152.

Comment: @ this.lau_  : No, I dont have McAfee installed...